# searchform.php doesn't work properly

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes

I made a searchform.php file to custom my search widget as I read, but when I use the search widget, it doesn't make the searches well, it sarches in the page of the categorie i'm writing. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s" ><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?> </label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Buscar..." name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="image" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/buscar.png" style="width:40%;" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`action="<?php  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">`

You forgot to `echo` out the URL, making the action attribute this:

`action=""`

This means the form is submitted to the current page, and since the current page is a category archive, it appends the `s` parameter to search inside that archive.

Normally you would instead use the homepage URL where WP will then load the `search.php` template and do a full search

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now it send me to the home page insead of searching...
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? Hence `home_url( '\')`, what happens if you visit `/?s=test`? On my site and any standard site it would bring up search results for the word test, if that's not the case on your site then something is terribly wrong/interfering with normal search functionality